# Cooking food for people in Giyur process (Eruv Tavshilin)

Tags: eruv-tavshilin

Good morning!
As I told the last time ... I am in the giyur process and have to answer a lot of questions. For the next one I do not have the faintest idea. Is someone able to help me?

---

**Question:**
May we cook or warm food (in relation to Eruv Tavshilin) for people who are in the Giyur process? Cite two Halachic authorities who allow it. Please, explain why they allow it.

---

**My considerations:**
As I did understand one is not allowed to cook (for Eruv Tavshilin) for a non-Jew. The fact that he/she wants to become one is not to the point. He/she is still not. The only practical solution I "guess" would be to let your "becoming Jewish"-friend eat from your portion as long as you did not had the intention to cook more food than usual.
This "solution" may have the advantage that one still can practise general (I should almost say global) hospitality as giving no food to your "becoming Jewish friends" is rather awkward.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First, why would Eruv Tavshilin make a difference? You're not allowed to cook for a non-Jew on Yom Tov for Yom Tov, forget Shabbos. But second, is this not a CYLOR question? Shouldn't this be closed as practical psak?

Comment: "May we cook or warm food for people who are in the Giyur process?" - doesn't mention Yom Tov at all!?

Comment: This question is very unclear to me. Are you asking about cooking in general? on _yom tov_? on _yom tov_ for _Shabas_? or what? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: First of all to all those 21-century sages who now the best for themselves and others ... if you do not understand a question ask the person friendly to clarify himself instead of subtracting "reputation". Secondly my question is literally taken from my studybook written by my rebbe. Thirdly I am apparently an illiterate person as I do not know what CYLOR means. And last but not least it is written down several times that my question is related to Eruv Tavshilin. I know your wisdom is endless but may be you are able to descend to my level without too much haughtiness. Thank you.

Comment: We lo ira, i'm sorry you're not getting the best first impression of our site. 1) I'd just like to clarify that downvotes aren't personal, they're just a signal that something should be improved, and can be undone after an edit. 2) While that may be true, for people unfamiliar with it, the question isn't exactly clear at first glance. 3) CYLOR = Consult Your Local Orthodox Rabbi. This question is not asking for practical psak, so don't worry about that. [continued]

Comment: [continued] 4) If i understand correctly, the intent of the question is this: "On Yom Tov, having made an Eiruv Tavshilin, may we cook or warm food for someone in the giyur process?" It may help to just explain the question a bit past your rabbi's textbook.

Comment: Dear (mr) Scimonster, Thank you for your explanation. Your "On Yom Tov, having made an Eiruv Tavshilin, may we cook or warm food for someone in the giyur process? is right." Apparently 2 halachic authorities think different about letting non-Jews eat. Sorry, my son told me that me yodea is not the same as an forum. May be my age made it more difficult. I am 67 and not versed to this all. But thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of [Eruv Tavshilin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruv_tavshilin) is to enable a Jewish person to cook for other Jewish people on Yom Tov for the Shabbos immediately following the Yom Tov.

A Jewish person [cannot cook](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/tues_09_24_13/) for a non-Jew on Yom Tov.

Therefore, it does not seem possible to cook or heat food  for non-Jews who are in the Giyur process on Yom Tov.   Eruv Tavshilin should not make a difference.

related: [Using Eiruv Tavshilin to Cook for a Gentile Shabbos Guest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/using-eiruv-tavshilin-to-cook-for-a-gentile-shabbos-guest?rq=1)

Please post an answer to the question here when you get the answer from your teacher so we can all learn. (Not my downvote).

Comment: I agree with you but the rebbe would not have asked if there were no exceptions. At least I guess :) I will ask the rebbe and post his answer. That may take another week. But I will tell you. Thanks for your nice answer.

Comment: I'm just wondering if anyone can develop this thought: [1] The Eruv helps a Jew prepare for Shabbos on Yom Tov. [2] There is no prohibition for a Jew to have a non-Jew eat with him on Shabbos. [3] So although it is not allowed to cook for a non-Jew on Yom-Tov, the outcome of the cooking is not forbidden.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a reference to a highly related question - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/using-eiruv-tavshilin-to-cook-for-a-gentile-shabbos-guest?rq=1 which differs only insofar as the non-Jew to be invited is in this case undergoing Giur.

Comment: @Weloira More than 2 weeks have gone by since you said it may take another week. Has there, please, been any progress?